# testing nodejs modules, best tutorials, approaches?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, express

I'm new to testing nodejs modules.
Is there a well organized tutorial out there that can get me going on testing the modules I've written in nodejs? I searched online, found some things but not sure what the best/most updated approach is to run tests on modules?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [many test frameworks available](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-testing) for node.js.  I recommend [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) (highly) or  [jasmine-node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) as good starting places.  [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit) and [vows](https://github.com/cloudhead/vows) are also widely used.

Other than that, this is a question better posed on google.com as it's not a specific programming question with a specific answer. [This jasmine tutorial](http://evanhahn.com/?p=181) looks good and the jasmine-node docs will tell you how to run it inside node.js instead of the browser, which is straightforward.